# Two approaches for determining the probability for the value of a random variable lead to different solutions

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. And
$$
Z = \text{sign}(Y)\cdot X = \begin{cases}
X, & Y\geq 0,\\
-X, & Y<0,
\end{cases}
$$
It can be proven that $P[Z\leq z]=\Phi(z)$.

Now lets determine the following Probability: $$P[X+Z=0]$$

My exercise book presents the following (nice and short) solution:
$$
P[X+Z=0] = P[Z=-X] = P[\text{sign}(Y)<0] = \Phi(0)= \frac{1}{2}.
$$
I can understand the solution of my exercise book. However, I also solved the exercise myself and came to a different solution with the following approach:

First I insert the definition of $Z$:
$$
\begin{align}
P[X+Z=0]
&=P[X+\text{sign}(Y)X=0] \\
&=P[X(1+\text{sign}(Y))=0]  \\
&=P[X=0\cup(1+\text{sign}(Y))=0] \\
&=P[X=0] + P[1+\text{sign}(Y)=0] - P[X=0\cap 1+\text{sign}(Y)=0]\\
&=P[X=0] + P[\text{sign}(Y)=-1] - P[X=0\cap \text{sign}(Y)=-1]
\end{align}
$$
Now I use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent:
$$
\begin{align}
&=P[X=0] + P[\text{sign}(Y)=-1] - P[X=0]\cdot P[\text{sign}(Y)=-1] \\
&=P[X=0] + P[Y\leq 0] - P[X=0]\cdot P[Y\leq 0] \\
&=\varphi(0) + \Phi(0) - \varphi(0)\cdot \Phi(0) \\
&=\varphi(0) + \frac{1}{2} - \varphi(0)\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} +\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{1}{2}. \\
\end{align}
$$
So my solution is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Pr(X=0)=0$. In particular, it is not $\varphi(0)$.

Comment: Thank you! I see, so I'm only allowed to used $\varphi$ to determine the density, and the probabilities of intervals (cumulative density) indirectly through $\Phi$. But $\varphi$ does not denote the probability of a specific value (it's just a density function). Now this brings up another question: Am I allowed to do the factoring into $Pr(X=0)$ and the other event as above as long as I assign 0 to Pr(X=0)? Or can't one do that with continuous variables?

Comment: You are welcome. The factoring was fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. So my cumbersome approach would also lead to $\frac{1}{2}$ if I assigned $0$ to $Pr(X=0)$ as you corrected.

Comment: The basic approach is fine, and will give the right result.